# "Recent inbox messages" button not always working

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

The "Recent inbox messages" button doesn't work when on Stack Overflow or MathOverflow sites; still works on the Meta sites.

I'm using Firefox 52.1.0 on CentOS.

Comment: There was just a question posted about this ~15 seconds ago (since deleted), apparently it's been fixed

Comment: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6460423#6460423

Comment: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/925749710375309312

Comment: _"Everybody has a testing environment. Some people are lucky enough enough to have a totally separate environment to run production in."_

Comment: Thanks for the lightning quick fix. :-)